# Questions about 1 time event

Tags: discussion

I just saw [Details on closure of Rte 120 into Yosemite? (Not normal snow closure.)](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15820/details-on-closure-of-rte-120-into-yosemite-not-normal-snow-closure).

Do we want to allow questions that are about a one time event, which will presumably be completely useless to everyone in a month or two when the event is over?

Comment: As the OP of the question in question, I point out that a closure of this magnitude into (and within) one of the premier national parks is not only of local and momentary interest, but may be an augury for a future of declining maintenance budgets and increasingly frequent anamalous  weather. Today, Big Oak Flat Road, tomorrow, Tioga Pass Road?  Or Trail Ridge Road?

Answer (score 7):

Answer without addressing the usefulness of Q&A about one time events that, will be solved soon.  I believe you have underestimated this particular event.

Original (Feb 2017} ["This road closure is anticipated to last several days, as road crews assess and repair the road."](http://www.sierrastar.com/news/local/article134365769.html) It is now several months into closure without an estimated completion date given.  There is only a single route left, which is subject to the same potential for loss of use.  The potential for future similar events remain.

This is a major event, effecting a major national park, it has current and historical significance.

Comment: Hi James Jenkins! It looks like this is more about the example question in Karen's post than her original title. Your first sentence even says so. I've asked her for clarification in case I'm wrong, but I think it would be more helpful if you answered what she asked, rather than focusing on the example question. Sometimes in meta posts (I don't have a specific example off the top of my head) example questions become the subject of the answers, thus being confusing to future readers. With all due respect, I don't want that to happen here.

Comment: @Sue I appreciate your comment and concerns. Without an example that is not addressed by the current closure reasons, it really hard to answer the title question.  I believe there is a post at https://meta.stackexchange.com that essentially says, asking and answering questions with a very limited audience are not in themselves bad actions, and these Q&A should not be deleted,  But I am not finding the post. .

Comment: James Jenkins, I definitely agree that a question like this would work best with a relevant example question. I thought this was one, but it turns out that's not really the case. Since OP hasn't commented or changed anything, I take back my objections. However, if you do happen to come across that meta SE discussion, I think it would be a worthwhile addition to this post. Thanks!

Comment: I found this [How useful must a question be to be allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70521) and looked through some others, but I think there is still another better one that I just have not found

Comment: @ab2 Glad you brought that up. I thought it was my computer that kept going to that question by accident. Thanks for fixing the link James! It's too bad "too localized" isn't a close reason anymore. That could have solved the problem for the rare times a situation like this would happen.

Comment: @sue maybe there is good reason why it is not a close reason any more

Comment: There is, and there are a number of discussions on Meta:SE which took place during the time the decision was made. I found some yesterday. I thought I saved them so I could add to this, but now I can't find them! I'll keep looking!

Comment: @sue if you voted on any of them, go to your meta profile. Just above your questions and reputation details select votes, this will show all the questions you have voted on. That should help you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I personally don't think that it should be a major issue.
On TGO we have 3,505 questions so far and I don't think adding one to it is an issue, unless its not directly suited.

While I do agree about your concern on allowing a question which might go obsolete after a deterministic span, I think few of us including the OP can flag the question for moderators to get rid of it after it is no longer applicable.

The only intention I have to do it this way is to attract web community (users) who specifically are looking for information about this particular event.

Comment: Hi WedaPashi! Just to clarify, deleting posts isn't always easy, so maybe we shouldn't post something we know will be obsolete. OP can only delete their question if it has no answers, or only one answer which has no upvotes, so this fails. OP can't delete their own answer if it's accepted, which this isn't yet. More information about deleting questions/answers is [here](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) and [here](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Mods have special deletion powers, but I don't know if they'd use them in a case like this.

Answer (score 2):

In old SE speak, that is the definition of a question that is too localized. A slight modification to the question would improve it in my mind. Specifically, asking where else to call besides the concierge desk at a hotel about road closures in Yosemite NP would be a great question. A great answer would demonstrate the usefulness of the suggested method by providing details about the current situation.

Comment: Interesting suggestion for improving the question.   I called the Ahwahnee because they sent me an e-mail about the closure (we have reservations there), and because I was sure of getting a human being instead of an automated response system.